# Existing help framework for iOS

Tags: ios

I'm looking for a framework to display "help instructions" on the different iPhone/iPad views.

By example we could add a "help instruction" linked to a view "tag" and the framework would be in charge of displaying the help instruction. This help configuration could be defined in an XML file.

Is this kind of framework available?

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't provide a help mechanism for iOS for a reason: a mobile user doesn't have the time to read manuals. Your app should be *extremely* obvious.

Most applications with table views explain functions and options with footer text. Avoid info longer than two lines of text.

I guess you could also use a gesture recognizer for long push to provide information in a small view when a user holds his finger on a function or option. But I don't recommend it, compared to the alternatives above.